postgres batch insert performance
Trying insert in postgres data by batch query in unlogged table by jdbc (spring jdbctemplate)
For 400-800 first batch query executed in 10-20ms
After some time it slowly to 400-500ms on 1 batch
If i reload postgres then speed return to 10-20ms
Table is:
create unlogged table recommendation_jsonb_unlog
(
    req_uuid text,
    some_id  text,
    data     jsonb
)

in app log get lines:
2024-04-23T23:06:47.861+03:00  INFO 9556 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] c.e.r.s.i.l.RecommendationServiceUnlog   : ca34f50a-9564-4612-a137-c75327d7791f: Chunk 258/418 saved by 421 ms
2024-04-23T23:06:49.141+03:00  INFO 9556 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] c.e.r.s.i.l.RecommendationServiceUnlog   : ca34f50a-9564-4612-a137-c75327d7791f: Chunk 259/418 saved by 427 ms
2024-04-23T23:06:50.432+03:00  INFO 9556 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] c.e.r.s.i.l.RecommendationServiceUnlog   : ca34f50a-9564-4612-a137-c75327d7791f: Chunk 260/418 saved by 419 ms

In jdbc logs i see pause in sunc and bind command (some time):
for example:
2024-04-21T01:06:36.482+03:00 TRACE 20908 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Bind ,type=VARCHAR ...)
2024-04-21T01:06:36.482+03:00 TRACE 20908 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Describe(portal=null)
2024-04-21T01:06:36.482+03:00 TRACE 20908 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Execute(portal=null,limit=1)
2024-04-21T01:06:36.482+03:00 TRACE 20908 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Bind,type=VARCHAR ...)
2024-04-21T01:06:36.520+03:00 TRACE 20908 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Describe(portal=null)
2024-04-21T01:06:36.520+03:00 TRACE 20908 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] o.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl   :  FE=> Execute(portal=null,limit=1)

first bind time lower than 1 ms, sencond 40ms
in postgres logs (enable auto explain):

2024-04-23 20:04:26.667 UTC [114] LOG:  duration: 10.593 ms  plan:
        Query Text: insert into recommendation_jsonb (req_uuid, some_id, data) values ($1, $2, $3::JSONB),($4, $5, $6::JSONB) [and 98 more]
        Insert on recommendation_jsonb  (cost=0.00..0.40 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=10.589..10.590 rows=0 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=174 dirtied=7 written=7
          WAL: records=64 bytes=53183
          ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.40 rows=32 width=96) (actual time=0.006..0.085 rows=32 loops=1)
2024-04-23 20:04:28.015 UTC [114] LOG:  duration: 10.276 ms  plan:


code for save is:
val batchData = chunk.map {
    mapOf(
        "reqUuid" to it.second[0].reqUuid,
        "someId" to it.second[0].someId,
        "data" to objectMapper.writeValueAsString(it.second)
    )
}.toTypedArray()
val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
    "insert into recommendation_jsonb (req_uuid, some_id, data) values (:reqUuid, :someId, :data::JSONB)",
    batchData
)
val execTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start

In postgres some settings added:
ALTER SYSTEM SET synchronous_commit TO 'off';
ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level  TO 'minimal';
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_senders  TO '0';
ALTER SYSTEM SET fsync  TO 'off';


A few days ago I managed to configure it so that the insertion speed was consistent 20-30 ms. But I lost that config and I can’t understand what the system is up against now
User postgres in docker (on single server), ssd (>300 mb/s for write) 8 gb ram, netwrok 1 Gbs
UPD 1:
Trying use temp tables, but nothing change
first two iteration 20-30ms
third 300ms
2024-04-24T04:51:46.259+03:00  INFO 3140 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] c.e.r.s.impl.temp.OfferServiceTemp       : Time to exec 'ffa39b09-4880-4efa-be07-db9e1394f2c8: Chunk 4/14 saved 22 ms
2024-04-24T04:51:46.535+03:00  INFO 3140 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] c.e.r.s.impl.temp.OfferServiceTemp       : Time to exec 'ffa39b09-4880-4efa-be07-db9e1394f2c8: Chunk 5/14 saved 27 ms

2024-04-24T04:53:54.975+03:00  INFO 3140 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] c.e.r.s.impl.temp.OfferServiceTemp       : Time to exec '91a8230f-64c3-434a-bbe0-984477b8e4cb: Chunk 7/14 saved 301 ms
2024-04-24T04:53:58.351+03:00  INFO 3140 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-4-thread-1] c.e.r.s.impl.temp.OfferServiceTemp       : Time to exec '91a8230f-64c3-434a-bbe0-984477b8e4cb: Chunk 8/14 saved 337 ms

monitoring iostat by 'iotop'. First ans second iteration use 6-7 Mb/s to write Third and onwards use 1.5 Mb/s (max)
One batch writes > 300ms independ of table size, i mean timing not grow with table size
UPD 2: using copy instead insert (CopyManager)
var start = System.currentTimeMillis()
dataSource.connection.use { con ->
    try {
        val copyManager = CopyManager(con.unwrap(BaseConnection::class.java))
        val copyIn = copyManager.copyIn("COPY recommendation_jsonb_unlog FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER")
        copyIn.writeToCopy(toByteArray, 0, toByteArray.size)
        copyIn.endCopy()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log.error("", e)
        throw e
    }
}
var end = System.currentTimeMillis()
log.info("Time to save rec in unlog: ${end - start} ms")

First 2-3 repeat get normal timing (15000-20000ms on pack)
2024-04-24T15:49:46.236+03:00  INFO 6692 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-3-thread-1] c.e.r.s.i.c.RecommendationServiceCopy    : Time to save rec in unlog: 14804 ms

After, timing grow x10
2024-04-24T15:54:19.625+03:00  INFO 6692 --- [recs-postgres] [pool-3-thread-1] c.e.r.s.i.c.RecommendationServiceCopy    : Time to save rec in unlog: 224432 ms

Question is: Why is insertion slow after 200-300 iteration?
UPD for question: I'm not looking for a way to quickly insert many rows, I want to find a bottleneck.

If you really want to speed things up then use CopyManager from here Postgres extensions.

Most likely it becomes slow because of background maintenance jobs. Try COPY, that's way faster than single inserts. By the way, I would never ever turn fsync off. Never.

What does it mean to "reload postgres"?  Are you just ending your session, then starting up again and resuming from where it left off?  Restarting the PostgreSQL server?  Truncating the table?  Dropping the entire database and reinitializing it?

What does it mean to "reload postgres"?

sudo reboot

but if leave postgres for 5 min in work (without read/write) then insert return in 20-30ms

"If you really want to speed things up then use CopyManager",
tried it, but it's not that fast (from there i think on tcp buffers or some else)

You didn't share any code using CopyManager, hard to help. But you might hit hardware and/or network limits. Compared to single INSERT's, COPY can be a 1000 times faster. But you do need enough resources

It sounds like you are dirtying pages faster than they can be written so they start to clog up the kernels page cache.

@Frank Heikens
append UPD 2 with CopyManager

Could you share some information about the database configuration parameters that you changed from the defaults?
